# PHP combine array all array elements

Tags: php, arrays

*Assuming I don't want to loop through and build a new array*, is there a built in way in PHP to add two arrays together and push all keys from the second array after the keys from the first? I Googled around and couldn't find anything that does exactly this, but wondering if anyone might know

For example to combine these..

```
array( 0 => "a", 1 => "b" );
array ( 0 => "c", 1 => "d" );
```

and get this..

```
array( 0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3 => "d" );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
array_merge(array( 0 => "a", 1 => "b" ),array ( 0 => "c", 1 => "d" ));
```

Or

```
array( 0 => "a", 1 => "b" ) + array ( 0 => "c", 1 => "d" )
```

This first one will overwrite duplicate keys, the second will not.  And you may have to sort the array afterwords.

Or, you could do:

```
array_merge(array_values(array( 0 => "a", 1 => "b" )), array_values(array ( 0 => "c", 1 => "d" )))
```

That will definitely work

Comment: Thanks dave, I actually looked at array_merge, looks like I just didn't pay close attention to the documentation.. doh!

Comment: Please note though, "overwrite duplicate keys" only applies to non-numeric keys. numeric keys are appended.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
<?php
$ab = array('a', 'b');
$cd = array('c', 'd');

var_dump(
    array_merge($ab, $cd)
);

/*
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "b"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "c"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "d"
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
    $array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

    print_r($result);

    /*
    Array
    (
        [0] => zero_a
        [1] => two_a
        [2] => three_a
        [3] => one_b
        [4] => three_b
        [5] => four_b
    )
    */
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)